Fill values with Pandas
I have two data frames.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
'Date': ['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-04', '2015-01-05', '2015-01-06', '2015-01-07', '2015-01-08', '2015-01-09', '2015-01-10', '2015-01-11', '2015-01-12'],
'Value_1': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({
'Date': ['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-04', '2015-01-05', '2015-01-06', '2015-01-08', '2015-01-09', '2015-01-11', '2015-01-12'],
'Value_2': [10, 10,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10]})

I want to use df1, put the two data frames side by side, and have the columns Date, Values_1, and Values_2.
But, the df2 has some missing data.
How can I pick the values based on the dates and, if they don't have a date, put np.NaN in the column?
The result should be like this:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
'Date': ['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-04', '2015-01-05', '2015-01-06', '2015-01-07', '2015-01-08', '2015-01-09', '2015-01-10', '2015-01-11', '2015-01-12'],
'Value_1': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10], 'Value_2': [10, 10, np.NaN, 10, 10, 10, np.NaN, 10, 10, np.NaN, 10, 10]})


As per the suggested duplicate, and if I understand you correctly, you want: df1.merge(df2, on='Date', how='left'), or df1.assign(Value_2=df1['Date'].map(df2.set_index('Date')['Value_2'])). If not, please review your question: none of your dfs are properly constructed.
